# Parabolic slide

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, physics

> Given a friction-less slide $y=x^2$, place a particle on the slide at
>   $(1,1)$. The particle is acted upon by constant gravity $g= 9.8$
>   units/s/s. At what time does it reach bottom?

The following is work done so far: 
Potential energy lost = Kinetic energy gained.
$$
mass \cdot g \cdot (1-y) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot mass \cdot \|\mathbf{v}\|^2 
$$
$$
\sqrt{2g(1-y)}= \|\mathbf{v}\|
$$
Here $m$ is slope of the curve at the particle's position
$$
v_x= -\| \mathbf{v} \| \cos{ \left( \arctan{m} \right) }
$$
$$
v_y= -\| \mathbf{v} \| \sin{ \left( \arctan{m} \right) }
$$
Here using trig identities
$$
\cos{ \left( \arctan{m} \right) } = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}
$$

$$
\sin{ \left( \arctan{m} \right) } = \frac{m}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}
$$

So
$$
v_x = -\| \mathbf{v} \| \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}
$$
$$
x' = -\sqrt{2g(1-x^2)} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(2x)^2}}
$$
and 
$$
v_y = -\| \mathbf{v} \| \frac{m}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}
$$
$$
y' = -\sqrt{2g(1-y)} \cdot \frac{2\sqrt{y}}{\sqrt{1+(2\sqrt{y})^2}}
$$

Comment: Work done so far:  Given conservation of energy under constant gravity, potential energy + kinetic energy = constant.

Comment: For a particle at (x,y=x^2), it has fallen by a height 1-y, hence mass*g*(1-y)= 1/2 * mass * v^2. So v= sqrt(2g(1-y))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you found

$$
\frac{\mathrm ds}{\mathrm dt}=\sqrt{2g(1-x^2)}\;.
$$

We also have

\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm ds}{\mathrm dx}
&=\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right)^2}
\\
&=\sqrt{1+4x^2}\;.
\end{align}

Thus

\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm dx}
&=\frac{\mathrm ds}{\mathrm dx}\cdot\frac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm ds}
\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{1+4x^2}{2g(1-x^2)}}\;,
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
t&=\int_0^1\mathrm dx\frac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm dx}\\
&=\int_0^1\mathrm dx\sqrt{\frac{1+4x^2}{2g(1-x^2)}}
\\
&=
\frac{E(-4)}{\sqrt{2g}}
\\
&\approx
\frac{2.63518}{\sqrt{2g}}
\\
&\approx0.595\text s\;,
\end{align}

([Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?dataset=&i=integral%20of%20sqrt%28%281%2B4x%5E2%29%20%2F%20%281%20-%20x%5E2%29%29%20for%20x%3D0..1) computation of the integral), where $E(m)$ is the complete elliptic integral of the second kind with parameter $m=k^2$.

Comment: amazing answer, thanks a lot